# Can't re-install photoshop cs6 from PlayOnLinux

Tags: playonlinux

I have successfully installed Microsoft Office and even installed Adobe AI from the past with the use of PlayOnLinux.

What happened was my free trial already expired for my Photoshop and I have read somewhere that you need to uninstall and re-install the application to get a free trial again, which I did.

Now, I can no longer re-install Photoshop CS6. Usually, there are 3 options for me. (1) Overwrite, (2) Erase and (3) Abort. But as you can see on the screenshot below, the **Overwrite** option is no longer available.

What did I do wrong with this? Thank you so much for any help.

[please check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nobpu.png)

Comment: If your free trial expired you need to buy a license or use alternative free software. What you're asking here is for how to circumvent a Windows software license. This is off-topic all the way.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Thank you for your response. I am planning to buy a license for this but my problem here is that I can't install it.

Comment: If you already installed you don't need to reinstall?!? And Adobe has zero support for installing it with Wine, unfortunately, so you're on your own if anything fails with your current, now expired, installation. But using PoL I'm sure you know you can create a new container (I probably said more than I morally should already).